# Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs (Specifically Blogger) (PHP)

Tags: php, zend-framework, oauth, blogger

Using Google's tutorials, I am attempting to access the Blogger API, using the OAuth 2.0 authentication method. I have successfully authenticated with OAuth, but I do not understand how to access the API's.

**All their examples run off of the object $gdclient** - which, if you use the AuthSub method, is set to Zend_Gdata_AuthSub::getHttpClient($_SESSION['sessionToken']);

**However, I can't seem to find what to set $gdclient to if you authenticated with OAuth2.0!** Any help please? The rest of the examples are straight forward, but as I mentioned, they all run off of $gdclient, which I have been unable to set so far.

Blogger API Tutorials: http://code.google.com/apis/blogger/docs/1.0/developers_guide_php.html

OAuth 2.0: http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2.html

Thanks!

Comment: I answered my own question, I think.

What it looks like is I don't use the $gdclient and all that zend framework - I just do curl calls to the links they call to. I discovered this looking at a full end-to-end example at https://github.com/jcleblanc/oauth/tree/master/oauth2-php-google although it was very hard to find.

If anyone has any additional comments, I'm always looking for better info! thanks!

Comment: Hi, I am in the same situation looking for a way to look up sales report in the google play android market. You know that google has some official api. Look at this page https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer

Answer (score -2):

form the heading: [3.c. ClientLogin username/password authentication](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/1.0/developers_guide_php?hl=nl#ClientLogin)

```
$user = 'user@example.com';
$pass = 'secretPasswd';
$service = 'blogger';

$client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($user, $pass, $service, null,
    Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::DEFAULT_SOURCE, null, null,
    Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::CLIENTLOGIN_URI, 'GOOGLE');
$gdClient = new Zend_Gdata($client);
```