# php application to retrieve google contacts with zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

THis is regarding to retrive my google contact using gdata library of zend framework. I am able to retrieve my all google contact with username and password. But i want something different like retrieve it with secret ky and seceret id for that i have regestered my application with outh2.0 in google console api and retrieve secrate key and seceret id. using this seceret id i am able to retrieve token as well but i dont know how to retrive my google contact using this token can any on help..

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/jcleblanc/oauth/tree/master/oauth2-php-google

This link was provided in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278449/using-oauth-2-0-to-access-google-apis-specifically-blogger-php) and has a complete example of fetching the Contacts feed with PHP and OAuth 2.0.

If you're trying to access the contacts of accounts in a Google Apps domain you administer, you can use two-legged authentication (2LO) and OAuth 1.0 in Zend. Then you generate a consumer key and consumer secret key, and create the http client like this:

```
$oAuthOptions = array(
    'requestScheme' => Zend_Oauth::REQUEST_SCHEME_HEADER,
    'version' => '1.0',
    'signatureMethod' => 'HMAC-SHA1',
    'consumerKey' => [YOUR CONSUMER KEY],
    'consumerSecret' => [YOUR CONSUMER SECRET],
    'xoauth_requestor_id' => [EMAIL OF ACCOUNT TO ACCESS]
);

$consumer = new Zend_Oauth_Consumer($oAuthOptions);
$token = new Zend_Oauth_Token_Access();

$client = $token->getHttpClient($oAuthOptions,null);
```

More on two/three legged authentication on OAuth 1.0: https://code.google.com/p/google-mail-xoauth-tools/wiki/PhpSampleCode

Comment: Thanks for reply, You are right i am using apps domain and able to generate token using that domain with passing consumer_key and consumer_seceret. i try with your code only change is i didnt pass 'xoauth_requestor_id' => [EMAIL OF ACCOUNT TO ACCESS]. but still it is not working.